# Bootstrap form-group align

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm currently working on an UI using Bootstrap 3. I have a `form-group` where I want to align a `span` on the left to a `h3`.

**My HTML:**

```
<div class="row">
   <nav class="col-sm-3">
      <div class="form-group">
         <span class="status" aria-hidden="true"></span>
         <h3>Project Title</h3>
      </div>
   </nav>
   <div class="col-sm-9">
      ...
   </div>
</div>
```

**My CSS:**

```
.status {
    width:20px;
    height:20px;
    border-radius:50%;
    background-color: yellow;
}
```

Somehow, the span never appears on the screen. The desired layout should be:

- Title

Do you know how to solve this?

Thanks :)

Comment: `.status {display: inline-block;}`

Comment: Can you provide a [mcve]?

Comment: Give some text value for the span and check it works fine.If you that class in div,instead of span.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can add just float:left in .status class:

```css
.status {
    width:20px;
    height:20px;
    border-radius:50%;
    background-color: yellow;
    float: left;
    margin-right: 10px;
}
```

```html
<div class="row">
   <nav class="col-sm-3">
      <div class="form-group">
         <span class="status" aria-hidden="true"></span>
         <h3>Project Title</h3>
      </div>
   </nav>
   <div class="col-sm-9">
      ...
   </div>
</div>
```